# Is .insert_str() dependent on what's in the string?

Tags: rust

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase my question, so I'll try and explain as best I can.

I'm trying to use Rust to write a UI for a program that runs in a terminal window.
The program has two tabs, and my thought was to draw the sides of the tabs, get the length of that row, subtract 2 to get the correct placement for their name and insert the name, to get something like:

```
╭────────╮╭───────────╮
│ Lingon ││ Blueberry │
```

Unfortunately I can't subtract without the program panicking.
If I remove the subtraction and add a println! to see the length at the end of each tab, it correctly prints 4 and 14, but nevertheless incorrectly inserts the names at 2 and 10.
If I change the "`\u{2502}`" to "`l`" (lower case L) it "correctly" places them at the 4th and 14th place respectively.

I simplified the original code as much as I could and also added a rust playground link at the bottom.

```
fn main() {
    let tab_names = vec!["Lingon", "Blueberry"];
    let win_cols = 100;
    let mut tab_rows = vec![String::with_capacity(win_cols); 2];

    for name in tab_names {
        tab_rows[0].push_str("\u{256d}");
        tab_rows[0].push_str(&std::iter::repeat("\u{2500}").take(name.chars().count()+2).collect::<String>());
        tab_rows[0].push_str("\u{256e}");

        tab_rows[1].push_str("\u{2502}");
        tab_rows[1].push_str(&std::iter::repeat("\u{0020}").take(2).collect::<String>());
        tab_rows[1].push_str("\u{2502}");
        
        let name_placement = tab_rows[1].chars().count();
        println!("{}\r", name_placement);
        tab_rows[1].insert_str(name_placement, name)
    }
    for i in 0..tab_rows.len() {
        println!("{}\r", tab_rows[i]);
    }
}
```

[Same code in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6380def615e5e8553457e0802706713)

**As I was editing my question before posting, I might have realized what the issue was.**
I've attempted to answer it myself, but be advised that I'm not a programmer and might just make an even bigger fool of myself. If anyone who knows the answer can verify, It'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *String* is a string of characters, where each character may be represented by more than one byte. Like, for exampe, the '`\u{2502}`' (vertical line) that I'm using, that is represented by three bytes.

The *insert_str(n)* method inserts strings at byte position *n*.

As I was trying to insert a *String* into a byte position that was inside a character, the program panicked.

Comment: This is true. You can use API like [String::char_indices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.char_indices) to calculate at which byte offset starts n-th character.